# Unity animation doesn't play after transitioning to a new scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to play an animation before switching to a new scene, load the scene and then play another animation after that. The code I use for this task is as follows:

```
    IEnumerator PlayTransitionAndLoadSceneCoro(string sceneName) {
        transition.SetTrigger("Start");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);

        AsyncOperation asyncSceneLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);
        while (!asyncSceneLoad.isDone)
            yield return null; // Block execution until the scene is loaded

        transition.SetTrigger("End");
    }
```

Both scenes use the same TransitionManager prefab, and my animator object is set up as follows:
[image]

But while the animation plays properly in the first scene, it doesn't play on the new scene (that also has the TransitionManager prefab) as shown in the gif below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `transition.SetTrigger("End");` in the `Start()` or `Awake()` function of next scene.

When you load the next scene, `transition.SetTrigger("End");` is never called or just called in the first scene.

Comment: Oh I see, I assumed it would still work since they use the same prefab file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understand, you should just use `Time.timescale = 1f;` line before your `transition.SetTrigger("End");` line